# Completely disable CollectionEditor

Tags: c#, propertygrid, collectioneditor

I'm using a custom dynamic class object in a PropertyGrid (too much code to post here).  In a nutshell, what it does is allow me to create properties at run-time from arbitrary input (in this case XML but that's beside the point). These properties may be any type, including another custom class so they can be nested indefinitely.

The issue I'm having is that the PropertyGrid sees this class as a Collection, and has the button in the Value column that allows you to open the CollectionEditor. This (among other things) has Add and Remove buttons, both of which will fundamentally break the custom class. Rather than try and make these two complicated systems work together nicely, I'd rather simply disable the CollectionEditor altogether. I have another system which allows you to see the child objects of the class (by setting the PropertyGrid.SelectedObject to the child object) and it works fine. I'd prefer the user not even having the option of seeing the CollectionEditor, as it seems to be not at all compatible with this system.

Ideally, I'd like to just put a button in the Value column that I could capture a click-event and handle myself, but that's optional. I also don't care if I disable the CollectionEditor for just the row(s) in question or for the whole PropertyGrid. I'm not using it either way, so anything which just makes it not accessible would be good.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried deriving your own CollectionEditor and in there override some methods/events to make its form not appear and just return without doing anything?

You then need to mark your collection type properties with:

```
[EditorAttribute(typeof(MyCollectionEditor), typeof(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor))]
```

This will automatically launch your MyCollectionEditor when clicking on the "..." button for the marked collection property in the PropertyGrid.

You may also need to inherit PropertyDescriptor and override the GetEditor method to return your own CollectionEditor.

Comment: Not sure how that would work - I'm not in charge of the CollectionEditor's appearance.  It's not referenced anywhere in my code.  (If it were, I wouldn't have this problem - I'd just make it not appear at all.)  How can I hijack the PropertyGrid's default behavior to make it use my own CollectionEditor instead of the built-in one?

Comment: Just inherit your own "MyCollectionEditor" from System.ComponentModel.Design.CollectionEditor and mark your collection type properties with  [EditorAttribute(typeof(MyCollectionEditor), typeof(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor))]

Comment: Hmm - that may be the direction to go.  However, the fact that this class is dynamically created at run-time complicates everything - you can't put attributes on properties because it doesn't HAVE any properties.  It's using a whole complicated nest of PropertyDescriptors and overriding GetProperties() to give its own list, so it's nowhere near as simple as just adding a decorator tag like that.  Anyhow, it'll be another week or so before I begin working on this again, I'm now on other parts of the project.  I'll let you know how that goes.

Comment: In that case you can inherit PropertyDescriptor and override the GetEditor method to return your own CollectionEditor.